# Class change doesn't affect onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and what I'm trying to do is fire `onmouseover` on one div (with class `active`), but on `onmouseout` change this class to `inactive` and class of second div switch from `inactive` to `active`. After this I expect that onmouseover will be now fired on second div (I am even using `.on()` so it should be live), but it won't. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv active first"></div> <div class="myDiv inactive second"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".active").on("mouseover", function () {
      $("#output").text("mouseover fired!");
   });

   $(".active").on("mouseout", function () {
      $("#output").text("");
      $(".first").addClass("inactive").removeClass("active");
      $(".second").addClass("active").removeClass("inactive");
   });
});
```

And here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgHmd/) for it. You can see in developer tools that the class is switched correctly, but event is still fired on first one.

Comment: use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am even using `.on()` so it should be live

Nope, `.on()` only has the [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) effect when passed a descendant selector argument:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".active", function () {
```

Instead of `document`, you may use the closest static `.active` container element for better performance.

---

Without the descendant selector argument, jQuery will directly attach event handlers only to the elements matched in the jQuery object `$('.active')` at the time it executes, exactly as the shorthand `.mouseover(fn)` and the older `.bind('mouseover', fn)` methods would.

Comment: Thanks! I get `.on()` funcionality wrong, but this works great.

Answer (score 0):

You actually add the on mouse over to the element with class="active", but it run once and when the second div has active class it has not been bound with the on mouse over event. You may need to rebind event again or bind all the element with the mouse event, mouseover -> active, mouseout -> inactive

Such as(bind event to all the elements):

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $('body').on('mouseover', '.myDiv', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
        $("#output").text( $(this).attr('class') );
    });
}
);
```

You can see more here http://jsfiddle.net/ZgHmd/6/

Hope this help.